# How would you have a certain Javascript snippet run only when a form is not being handled?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, handle

I have a piece of Javascript I want to run when a form loads. The form handles itself. When the form loads the Javascript works great, but when the form is submitted and the page handles itself the Javascript breaks it.

Is there a way to make the Javascript only run when the form is not being handled?

**UPDATE:**

I get this error when the form is handled (the Javascript is doing a AJAX request):

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load [ajax request url] Origin [original page] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="#" action="post">
    <!--form elements-->
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("invitestar-message").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        var signup = document.getElementById("invitestar-content-container");
        setTimeout(function(){
            body.removeChild(document.getElementById('invitestar-verifying'));
            signup.style.display = "block";
        }, 500);
    }
}

ajax.open("GET","http://nvrforget.com/invitestar/check-invite/?invite=kNdqyJTjcf",true);
ajax.send();
```

The domain that this javascript is run on is not `http://nvrforget.com/`.

Comment: Can you share code? Are you cross-domain Ajax?

Comment: Well some browser by default does not allow cross-domain Ajax call.

Comment: What do you mean "when the page handles itself, the javascript breaks it"?  What doesn't happen that should?  What does "page handles itself" mean?  We can't help without either a lot better description of what's causing the problem or posting the relevant code.

Comment: @Book of Zeus is there any way to change that default behavior?

Comment: What does "when the page is handled mean"?  The code will show us what it's doing and how to stop it from doing that when you don't want.  If you're not going to post some code or explain yourself better, I will have to vote to close an unaswerable because we have nothing to go on now.

Comment: What action in that code are you trying to stop from happening?

Comment: @jfriend00 making the ajax call occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [ajax request url] Origin [original page] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

is caused because you can't make ajax calls to a different domain than the web page is located on.  See this description of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is a way to make cross-origin ajax calls.  It requires a cooperating server (to implement the server side of the JSONP) and a method of adding the ajax request as a script tag.  Libraries like jQuery or YUI support the client-side parts of JSONP or you can do it yourself (but you still need a cooperating server).  Google JSONP if you want to know more about it.

Comment: ok, is there a way to do this then? because I need to make ajax calls to a different domain.

Comment: I added more to my answer about JSONP.